# What could it be?

Tags: cipher, visual

What could it be? Hmm... Try complete the picture!

[image]

Hint1a:

> [image]

Hint1b:

> [image]

Hint1c(strong):

> numbers...or?

Hint1d(stronger):

> 4 1 25 (In this *exact* order)

Comment: The difficulty here (as I perceive it) isn't working out what the rings equate to (which I believe your hints confirmed for me right from hint 1a) but exactly why only some of them are shaded in each shape's quadrant... Are we to assume that all relevant shading in the triangle and pentagon sectors has been filled in already, and we are just trying to complete the square and hexagon sectors? It's hardest to work out which parts are complete or incomplete really... Thanks.

Comment: Also, here's a friendly suggestion - have you considered making your titles more relevant to the puzzle theme? You could always hide a clue in the title instead of adding new hints every few hours, then just add specific hints every couple of days if there's been no interaction - people are probably trying to solve it offline, coming back to it from time to time... No need to rush the reveal - believe in your puzzle and in the community's ability and willingness to solve it :)

Comment: Ok... I can say that none of the 4 quadrants are complete. And yes, you're right about that :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the complete picture looks as follows

> [image]

Reasoning

> If we convert the numbers in the large triangle to letters and read from bottom right clockwise, it spells out DAY. Given that the circle has seven concentric annuli, we realise that it has to do with the days of the week.
>  Now, we know that in English before the DAY part of the word, each day has either 3,4,5 or 6 letters and the circle is split into four quarters denoted by a triangle, square, pentagon and hexagon. If we assign the inner annulus to Monday and proceed outwards, the process is to shade in the quarter of the annulus which corresponds to the number of letters in the first part of the name of the day of the week - so Monday, Friday, Sunday in the triangular quarter, Tuesday in the square quarter, Thursday and Saturday in the pentagon quarter and Wednesday in the hexagon quarter.

Comment: This may *be* right, but I think the other answer *feels* right ;)

Comment: This is the correct answer! Well done :)

Answer (score 8):

Well, it could be

> a terminator vision aiming grid

so you would complete the picture like this:

> [image]
>  <sup>original image copyright [these guys](https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/suai-ihpcnt/terminator-vision-system-1f9374) (GPL3+)</sup>

(..Yyyyeah, sorry, I may have had a few..) X-]

Comment: Almost, very close! ;D